# Complex imperfectly crossed three level model - advice on data and analysis sought

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

I have a question about a multi-level model. I have data from three related sources.

- Data on about 30 hospitals, at hospital level - things like size, teaching/non-teaching and so on.
- Data from about 1500 nurses, sampled from about 100 wards, either medical or surgical, in these 30 hospitals.
- Data from about half a million hospital admissions to these 30 hospitals, classified as to medical or surgical. No idea which specific ward they were in!

There is absolutely no way to link nurses to admissions, beyond assuming that the nurses on surgical wards, represent the nurses caring for surgical patients in that hospital, and similarly for the nurses on medical wards.

I can easily see how to link hospital data and admissions, or hospital data and nurses. The bit I'm struggling with is the 3-level model. I had hoped to use lmer in R to do the analysis.

I can easily merge hospitals and nurses, or hospitals and admissions - there is a 1:1 relationship, and I end up with a data set with 1500 rows, for the Hospital-Nurse merge, and 500,000 rows for the Hospital-Admission merge.

The equivalent Hospital-Nurse-Patient data file has about 25 million records - roughly 50 nurses per hospital added to each of roughly 17,000 admissions per hospital! This seems unreasonable to me. and I  would expect wildly incorrect standard errors at the least from the data multiplication, (but I might be wrong about that).

I could, of course, and indeed I have, prepared hospital level summaries of the nursing variables, and used these. However, this seems vaguely wrong. There is considerable variation between nurses within hospitals, and most of this information is lost if I take a hospital level mean instead.

So, what data structure should I use and how should I prepare it (preferably in R), and how do I accommodate the non-nested nature of these data?

The outcome variables of interest are all binary.

Advice, references, criticism all gratefully received.

Comment: I assume you'll aggregate the nursing information and add it as a hospital characteristic to the model of patient level outcomes.

Comment: I am doing that, but it seems that I am ignoring the variation between nurse within each hospital, which is quite considerable. A 3-level model looks more natural to me.

Comment: I know Linda Aiken at Penn has published on this sort of thing - but what I've seen has been GEE/2-level models. It might be a lack of knowledge, I just haven't seen 3-level models. Likely many reasons for this, many of which you've listed in your question. Would be curious what others think.

Comment: I know Linda's work, in fact she is one of the PI's on the project of which this work is a part, but I'm trying to extend some of that work. I'll keep struggling on!

Comment: Did you make some progress on this? If so maybe you could now answer your own question!